# Placement of Save Button in ArcGIS Javascript AttributeInspector dijit

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I am having a problem with an AttributeInspector that I noticed also exists in an online sample here: http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/ed_attribute_inspector/

If you click on a polygon to display the AttibuteInspector, you will notice that hovering your mouse over the upper right of the delete button selects the save button. In the Chrome console, I was able to find that there is a rogue  tag that might be causing this issue. See attached screenshot.

[image: Imgur]

The code that created this is as follows and is seen in the sample code [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/ed_attribute_inspector.html).

```
var saveButton = new Button({ label: "Save", "class": "saveButton"});
domConstruct.place(saveButton.domNode, attInspector.deleteBtn.domNode, "after");
```

How can this issue be avoided so that no parts of the two buttons or their containers overlap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a possible CSS problem - I'd report it to Esri tech support to see if they can fix it properly in the JS API.

As a workaround you may be able to tweak the CSS yourself to avoid the overlap. Eg try something like this:

```
.saveButton {
    margin-left: 45px;
}
```

Comment: That method doesn't cut it... it messes the layout completely :-(

Comment: @mahdi if not exactly that CSS (it worked for me in my quick test, but I didn't spend hours on it) then try something similar. Until Esri fix the widget I think we're stuck with trying to workaround the problem using hacks like this

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I fixed it later today. It is a CSS bug, and here is how I patched it for now:

```
attInspector.deleteBtn.domNode.classList.remove("atiButton");
```

The problem is that in the the CSS class atiButton has a fixed 16px size (geared towards the navigation buttons) and the delete button should not inherit from it, or better yet, the class should change and a new atiNavButton should have the fixed size, etc.